# Gnome: forcing an application to start on top

Tags: gnome, xfce

I am having issues with starting Thunar (a file manager for Xfce) via a keyboard shortcut and having it start on top of other windows.

The Thunar window always appears **below** the current active window, whilst of course I would want it  **above** it.  Apparently, only Thunar behaves like this, because if I start other applications -- I have tried with Gedit and GVim -- they appear on top (as expected).  Thunar behaves like this even when I start it via the Gnome Panel.

Maybe the problem is that Xfce applications don't start properly under Gnome?

I know that `wmctrl` allows you to raise any window, but I have no way to identify the last Thunar window and raise it because I could have other Thunar windows opened already.
Thank you.

Comment: Why is a new window being displayed below others in the first place? It sounds like something is buggy. I see from tags you're using Gnome; are you running the default window manager? Are other programs setting "always on top" hints? (You can check the latter with `xprop` and looking for [related EWMH hints](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#STACKINGORDER)).

Comment: @Anko: Thanks.  Apparently only Thunar behaves like this.  I have updated my question.

Comment: You didn't really answer any of my questions…

Comment: @Anko: Sorry.  Yes, I am using the default window manager.  No, as far as I can see, other programs are not setting "always on top" hints.  However, I have noticed that Thunar is a Xfce application: maybe this causes the problem.